# How can I make google endpoints API to use Firebase authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I've set up a very simple REST API on top of the awesome endpoints-proto-datastore library, which relies on endpoints v1.0.0 included in Google Cloud Built-in Third-party Libraries.

This API serves data to an Angular 6 app.

I've set up Firebase/Angularfire authentication as well. Now, when I try to authenticate API calls using Firebase following the example in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/authenticating-users#authenticating_with_firebase_auth), I can't use the Firebase "issuer" object required as it is not available in endpoints v1.0.0.

Seems the solution is to upgrade endpoints, which I do to v4.3.0 (latest as of today, I've also tried v2, v3).

When I run my app, the API does not accept calls to /_ah/spi anymore:

```
ValueError: Invalid request path: /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the [migration docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/migrating), in the new Endpoints version, you accept requests on `/_ah/api` instead of `/_ah/spi`

Comment: Thanks. The migration doc was very useful. I got the API to accept requests on /_ah/api, but I still can't access the firebase user info as endpoints.get_current_user() returns None. Not sure if it is an issue happening in dev/localhost only or if there is something else. The migration doc does not mention anything about deploying the service (swagger.json) either - do you know if this is something required when using the endpoints-proto-datastore library?